# Having troubler understanding why my error telling me my function is a view even though I have not declared that?

Tags: solidity

As title suggest, the `setNFTData()` function inside of my `tokenURI()` function is giving me the error `Function cannot be declared as view because this expression (potentially) modifies the state.` even though I am not calling this as a view. Could anyone help me to understand why this error is occuring? I have checked through other questions but no answers make sense in my case.

```
uint256 _user_nft_number;

function setNFTData(uint256 _itemID) public {
        _user_nft_number = _itemID;
        console.log(_user_nft_number);
    }

    // Set the NFT's metadata
    function tokenURI(uint256 _tokenId) public view override returns (string memory) {
        require(_exists(_tokenId));
        setNFTData(_tokenId);
        return string(
            abi.encodePacked(
                "data:application/json;base64",
                string.concat("data:application/json;base64")
            )
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your `tokenURI` function is declared as `view` but it is also trying to call your `setNFTData` function that modifies the state (`_user_nft_number = _itemID`). Hence, you get this error: `Function cannot be declared as view because this expression (potentially) modifies the state.` So you need to rid the `view` modifier in your `tokenURI` function if you want to call your `setNFTData` function inside it.